# Which framework is best for web based app

Tags: python

I have a program written in python. I wan to create a site, which provides the results from the site in a web page. The web-page takes input from user process data by the python [program and gives output in the web[age. I have heard that there are web frameworks like web2py, flask, django etc. The site has only minimal data to work on. Which one should I use?

Comment: If you use database, choose django, you will never regret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only tell my opinion, because there is no right or wrong answer. If you have a small project, use a microframework like bottle.py, cherrypy..., if you have a HUGE project it might pay off to get familiar with a full-blown framework with database-integration like django.